# simulate suspended and dehydrated messages in BizTalk server

Tags: biztalk

First of all, I don't know if this is the right place for this kind of question. Please tell me if it is not.

> For a demo of a monitoring application. I want to force some sendports
>   and orchestrations to get an instance with suspended and dehydrated
>   messages

How can I do this in BizTalk 2013?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a suspended message:
Just create a receive port and a receive location without a send port that matches the subscription. This will create 2 suspended messages: your actual message and a routing failure.

To get a dehydrated orchestration, create an orchestration with a delay shape that waits for example 1 hour. It will not stay active, instead it will dehydrate.

Hope this helps!

Pieter